# Create Xml From NodeList

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have XmlNodeList ,which I got from other xml dataObject,and I want to create new XML document from the child Nodes of dataObject. How can I do that?

```
XmlNodeList childNodes = dataObject.GetXml().ChildNodes;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy following :

```
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Root></Root>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            foreach (XmlNode node in childNodes)
            {
                root.Add(node);
            }
```